# Saving filepath to XML

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to write a startup file path to an existing XML file. I can read the filename from this xml but I can't seem to save a new path. My existing XML File is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<tisurvey>
    <startfile>P:\AGM SURVEYS\CARTHAGE TO LUFKIN\2014 DATA\TEST.accdb</startfile>
</tisurvey>
```

My code is:

```
public static void SaveStartUpPath(string appDataPath, string filePath)
    {
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();

        try
        {
            xmlDoc.Load(appDataPath + "\\tisurvey.xml");
            XmlNodeList xNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//tisurvey/startfile");
            foreach (XmlNode xNode in xNodes)
            {
                if (xNode.Name == "startfile")
                    xNode.InnerText = filePath;
            }
            xmlDoc.Save(appDataPath + filePath);
        }
        catch (Exception erx)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Xml File: " + appDataPath + 
                                "\\tisurvey.xml " + " Saving Path: " + filePath + 
                                " - " + erx.Message);
        }
    }
```

The error i get as an exceptions is:

> Xml File: C:\Users\cmh\AppData\Local\tir\TISurvey\1.0.0\tisurvey.xml 
>   Saving Path: C:\Users\cmh\Documents\TIR\Project Data\HOBBS TO WHITE
>   LAKES.accdb - The given path's format is not supported.

Any idea what my code should be or why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to save the `XmlDocuemnt` to `appDataPath + filePath` which is invalid path. The path was something like this (you may want to print `appDataPath + filePath` to be sure) :

> C:\Users\cmh\AppData\Local\tir\TISurvey\1.0.0C:\Users\cmh\Documents\TIR\Project Data\HOBBS TO WHITE LAKES.accdb

Comment: You are absolutely correct. That was a bonehead mistake.